# Django - How to extend a template from within an app correctly

Tags: python, django, templates

I am working on a Udemy class to get back into Django development, and this class has me doing the templates folder differently than I am used to. This is the current directory for my file structure showing where my templates are located:

[VS Code Directory Structure and extended template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb9Ak.png)

I can't embed yet, so this is the best I can do. Please ignore the ARCHIVES directory, that is just there while I test things out. I am trying to extend store.html off of base.html, but to test things, I am trying to extend from 'test.html' which you can see in the image.

Historically, I have always added the templates directory to the top level, but this class has them on the app level. My problem here is that I can't get the store.html to show up. The test.html (base) is showing up fine, but I can't extend off of it and I have tried messing with the {% extends './test.html' %) as far as using 'store/test.html', 'test.html', and '../test.html'. I know this latter one goes back another directory level, but I just wanted to state that I have been trying to change where it looks.

A few things: my settings.py has 'store' added, and the test.html is showing up with my nav bar just fine. I have APP_DIRS' set to True in my templates portion of settings.py My urls.py in my store app has 'path('', views.store, name='store'),' for the URL pattern, and then my views in the app have a function to render the view for the app and that seems to be working fine [views.py at app level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8OO3.png).

I even went on codeply to make sure my code in store.html was set up right for bootstrap, and it works. I also added it to test.html in the body and that makes it show up right too, it just will not extend and show off of the store.html. This is probably a simple mistake on my end, but I am struggling to get this to work and can't continue until I get this part working. Can someone please give me some advice/help?

Comment: Please, [*do not upload images of code/data/errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: Can you show the TEMPLATES dict of your settings.py ?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to define your BASE_DIR in your projects settings.py file. This is used to build absolute file paths for various parts of your project.

This would look something like this:

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

You can then use this to construct paths to directories within your project. In your case this would be within your store app but I would generally recommend keeping base.html files, and other static elements in their own directory if they're going to be used across your site.

For example, say you keep them in a file called templates, in your settings.py file you would construct a path as follows:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The key here is the DIRS item, join BASE_DIR with your directory, in this example 'templates', but it could be anything.

You can then refer to base templates within other html templates as:

```html
{% extends 'base.html'%}
```

Where 'base.html' is the name of your file.